# Insert multiple images randomly into different table cells using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new in Javascript/Jquery, currently still learning and so here I am seeking help. I would like to insert different images randomly (the location changes everytime i refresh the page) into table cells using Javascript/Jquery and not touching HTML/CSS.

I have tried using append to insert the images, however every image appears in all table cells which weren't what I wanted. I have also tried backgroundrepeat: no repeat but it doesn't work. It would be good if there's some simple coding that would work, so it will be easier for me to understand.

- I can't use getElementById cause my separated js file can't detect the ID from the HTML file

HTML:

```
<table id="Image">
<tr>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=1></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=2></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=3></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=4></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=5></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=6></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=7></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=8></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=9></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=10></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my jQuery best try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ImageHere").append("<img src='images/card.jpg' width='100%' height='100%' />" ) });
});
```

Comment: Could you also show us your JS code?

Comment: I deleted the codes that don't work so basically only left with: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ImageHere").append("<img src='images/card.jpg' width='100%' height='100%' />" )
});

Comment: `value` is not a valid attribute for `<div>`. Use `data-*` attributes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. `HTMLDivElement` does not have a `value`attribute. Use `data-value` instead.

Here's an example. For the sake of simplicity, this inserts `<hr />` instead of images. Adjust at your own pleasure.

```js
const imageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#Image .ImageHere');

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', insertRandomHr)

function insertRandomHr() {
  imageDivs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imageDivs.length)].innerHTML += '<hr />';
}
```

```css
#Image { width: 100%; }

.ImageHere::before { content: attr(data-value); }
```

```html
<table id="Image">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=1></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=2></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=3></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=4></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=5></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=6></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=7></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=8></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=9></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="ImageHere" data-value=10></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="foo" type="button">Insert &lt;hr /&gt; into random div</button>
```

**Hint:** If the sole reason to have those invalid `value` attributes in the first place was to use that for randomly assigning the image to a div, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help!

```
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ImageHere')];
const images = 
[
'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d4/7e/9e/d47e9e4a28894bfbd416b4f53ca15b95.jpg', 
'https://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/thumb/1/16/Sunset-in-pennsylvania-960px.jpg/285px-Sunset-in-pennsylvania-960px.jpg',
'https://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/thumb/a/a0/F26-final-night-default-wallpaper-standard.png/300px-F26-final-night-default-wallpaper-standard.png',
'https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/file/Elden-Ring/elden-ring-wiki-screenshot-art-trailer5.jpg?v=1560119240021',
'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D9oueVsX4AAW3Wk.jpg',
'https://pub-static.haozhaopian.net/static/web/appv2/images/landscape29bb2ef5b72f60c71199d5c22c979eadc.jpg',
'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462899006636-339e08d1844e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80',
'https://picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/free-stock-images-1080x720.jpg',
'https://destinations.com.ua/storage/crop/articles/avatar_291_max.jpg',
'https://get.wallhere.com/photo/sunlight-women-outdoors-women-model-portrait-blonde-long-hair-nature-photography-dress-Xenia-Kokoreva-river-fashion-hair-white-clothing-spring-Person-skin-clothing-supermodel-girl-beauty-season-woman-lady-photograph-blond-portrait-photography-photo-shoot-brown-hair-art-model-320309.jpg'
];
const suffelImages = shuffle(images);

function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

divs.forEach((div, i) => {
  div.innerHTML = `<img src="${suffelImages[i]}" />`;
});
```

// CSS

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to generate a random index from all the image containers that you have created in your table cells. You could then insert a programmatically created image element in the image container located at the generated index.

**Example:**

```js
// Returns a random index, from 0..max
const randomIndex = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));

// Returns an image element with a random image
const createImage = () => {
  const el = document.createElement('img');
  el.src = 'https://picsum.photos/100';
  return el;
};

// List of all image containers
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.ImageHere');

// Generate random index and add an image to the container at that index
const index = randomIndex(containers.length);
containers[index].appendChild(createImage());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table id="Image">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ImageHere"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Absolutely. Added something that I hope explains my reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You can first define array of your images which need to be inserted , then make this array arrange values randomly , then using `.forEach` JS function Or `.each` JQuery Function to loop and insert these images into your table randomly

let's start with this code and read my comments on it to understand what i mean better

```js
var images= ['image1.jpg','test.png','logo.png'] // array of your images
var randomArr = [] // new empty array which will have random values
for(var i= 0 ; i < images.length;i++){
 var item = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
  // this condition to prevent doublicate elements
 if(!randomArr.includes(item)){
  randomArr.push(item)
 }else{
  i = i - 1;
 }
}

// now we have new array with random images 
// lets start to insert these images into table
$("table#Image .ImageHere").each(function(index, value){
  if(index > randomArr.length) {
    // check if elements more than array of images and set default image
    $(this).html("<img src='default.jpg' />")
    }else{
    $(this).html("<img src='"+randomArr[index]+"' />")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Image">
<tr>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=1>ddd</div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=2></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=3></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=4></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=5></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=6></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=7></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=8></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=9></div></td>
<td><div class="ImageHere" value=10></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ImageHere').item(n)
```

or

```
$('.ImageHere').eq(n)
```

where `n` is the index of a random number.

Comment: Not sure why my solution was downvoted. The post clearly states the problem is that all of the cells have an image inserted when targeting only one. There's not really a reason to even see the JS for this.

Comment: Your comment is not constructive.